# Problems in parsing variables from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

> **Scenario:** For tracking events(Add to cart, Search terms,
>   Product views, etc) from a test e-commerce website(Opencart), JavaScript
>   function is written in the footer page and these functions are called
>   at button triggers or page loads.

**Problem:**
While tracking product view event following code is added to Product page, function `captureProductView()` is called from footer, and parameters `clientid, fname, lname` are retrieved from `getClientDetails();`

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
     getClientDetails();
     captureProductView('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>',
            '<?php echo $product['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['price']; ?>',
            clientid, fname, lname);
};
</script>
```

But the values from php variables `$product['product_id']`, `$product['name']`, `$product['price']` cannot be parsed to the script tag, leaving Notice:

> Notice : Undefined variable: product in
>   **/home/path.../product.tpl** on line **29**"

for all those three variables

I tried assigning these values to javaScript variables, which also did not work.

```
var p_id = "<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>";
var p_name = "<?php echo $product['name']; ?>";
```

Is there a way where I can parse the php variables to the script tag, so that they can be passed as parameters to the function?

Comment: Are you sure the `$product` variable has values? Or is defined?

Comment: PHP executes on the Server, before any information is sent to the Client, as in HTML, CSS, or JavaScript.

Comment: @Rax Weber, It has values. I am able to pass them in a function written on a Button onclick inside the php code.

Comment: Client side coding, will not produce Server Side code. `<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>` executes before your Client Side code is rendered as HTML, and JavaScript. If you want a Client Side Event to get information from the Server, use AJAX. But really, it's a definition issue, for starters.

Comment: @PHPglue, I am not familiar with ajax, Can you post an example as answer?

Comment: See [Step 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_5_%E2%80%93_Working_with_data).

Comment: @PHPglue Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because the associative array `$product` is not defined in the PHP script that renders the page.

Your first option is to edit the script so that `$product['product_id']`, `$product['name']`, `$product['price']` are defined and assigned with the proper values.

Note that your first snippet of code have a syntax error as you're mis-using the single quote. You have to use both single and double quotes:

```
 captureProductView('<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>',
                    '<?php echo $product["name"]; ?>', 
                    '<?php echo $product["price"]; ?>',
                    clientid, fname, lname);
```

---

You have a second option that is parsing with JavaScript the values from the rendered page.

```
 captureProductView( $('input[name=product_id]').val(),
                     $('h1').text().trim(),
                     $('.price').text().trim(),
                    clientid, fname, lname);
```

This worked on a layout I tried but may need minor changes on a different layout to target the appropriate page elements to fetch the values from.

Note I used jQuery to retrieve the value from the page elements.

The value for price is a string like `"Price:    $24"` and depending on your needs may require further basic string manipulation to extract only the price value (`24` in the example).

For reference I tried the above on this page:

http://themes.webiz.mu/opencart/apparel/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=69

**However** I strongly discourage this approach because as the layout changes the function may break.

---

All the above two options assume that `captureProductView` is properly sending the data to the server with an AJAX request and `clientid`, `fname`, `lname` are defined in the JavaScript code.